# Is it possible to get analytics on PAST website activity - Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, analytics, google-analytics-firebase

Is there a way with Google Analytics, or maybe with something else, to get the old analytics information on the wordpress website? I have not used any kind of analytics to track visitation. 
So sorry if this is a stupid question or does not make sense.

Comment: In my point of view, it's not possible..!

Comment: As others have said it's not possible with Google Analytics.. But you can however in cpanel or what ever your hosting provider uses, see the statistics of the domain. For example in cpanel, you can locate awstats for the domain and it will show you everything from keyword search to search engines etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not possible to use JS(Google Analytics, etc) to access past visitors. The only thing you can possibly do, I would assume, is viewing the past server logs and seeing whos accessed the site by I.P. You could possibly parse this to show unique ones, showing unique visitors.

Though it's not at all accurate, that's the only option you have as far as I'm aware.

Answer (score 0):

Go to http://www.alexa.com/ Find you user count, old your traffic